# How to update table1 based on updated values in table 2

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql tables:  Projects and Outlets.  The structure of the tables are as follows:

Projects:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+----------+---------------+
| id | ProjectName | ProjectDescription          | projType | projectStatus |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+----------+---------------+
|  1 | RA_Surf     | Retail Audit for Surf Excel |        1 |             1 |
|  2 | RA_Nirma    | Retail Audit for Surf Nirma |        1 |             1 |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+----------+---------------+
```

Outlets:

```
+----+------+------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+---
| id | pid  | poid | OutletName     | interviewer | Status | 
+----+------+------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+---
|  1 |    1 |   11 | Ganapathy Entp |           1 |      2 |             
|  2 |    1 |   21 | Suresh Entp    |           1 |      2 |             
|  3 |    2 |   32 | Suresh Entp    |           1 |      1 |             
+----+------+------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+-
```

The pid in outlets references id in projects.  I am trying to update the projectStatus in projects to 2 when the Status of all the outlets in outlets table pertaining to same pid is set to 2.

In the below table the Status for outlets is already set 2 where the pid is 1.  pid 1 refers to first record in projects table with id 1.

I have tried the following:

```
update projects 
set projectStatus=2 
where id=(
            select projects.id 
            from projects 
                join outlets on projects.id=outlets.pid 
            where Status = 2 
            group by outlets.pid 
            having (count(Status) * 2) = sum(Status)  
            );
```

I am getting an error `ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'projects' for update in FROM clause`

whereas when i use a select statement,

```
select id 
from projects 
where id = (
            select projects.id 
            from projects 
                join outlets on projects.id=outlets.pid 
            where Status = 2 
            group by outlets.pid 
            having (count(Status) * 2) = sum(Status)   
            );
```

this works.

How do I update the table, when the status of all the outlets in a project is updated to 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE Projects p
JOIN Outlets o ON p.id = o.pid
SET p.projectStatus = 2
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM Outlets oo
                   WHERE p.id = oo.pid
                     AND COALESCE(oo.Status, 0) != 2 )
```

### Update

In response to your comment about `COALESCE`, it is possible that the record in slave table contains NULL in checked field. COALESCE() converts this special value to common zero value.

If `Outlets.Status` column is defined as NOT NULL in the table's structure then the function usage is excess, and simple `AND oo.Status != 2` is enough.

Comment: thank you...this worked...could you please help me understand what coalesce do or why my update statement did not work.